# Electronic-only contributions in journals

Tags: publications

One of my manuscripts accepted for publication recently. The accepted manuscript exceeds the prescribed page size (16 p.) as per the journal policy. We will have to pay charges for additional pages in the manuscript. To avoid this, the editor suggested us to publish our paper as electronic-only contribution. Will it have all the indexing as a printed paper? (I mean issue, volume, and page numbers)..

Comment: Have you checked the index to see what it did in the past?  And have you asked the editor?

Comment: No would be surprising.

Comment: Ask the journal for the implications of electronic-only publication. Policies can differ.